# Why is the final row of this truth table for an SR flip flop not undefined

Tags: digital-logic

My textbook (Fundamentals of Digital Logic, Brown and Vranesic) has this truth table for an SR flip flop and I'm wondering why the last row is not undefined for Q(t+1).

[image: SR Flip Flop Truth Table]

Comment: Because this is how some real implementations work.

Comment: Fundamentals of Digital Logic, Brown and Vranesic.

Answer (score 1):

The table shows that there is a priority for set and reset inputs, `S` and `R`.

`R` always wins. If set and reset are both asserted on the next clock rising edge, the flip-flop will be reset.

`Q(t)` is only shown in the table when `S` and `R` are both negated. `Q` and `/Q` will be unchanged, so the `Q(t)`/`Q(t+1)` notation is used to express 'output is the same after the next clock as it is now'.

Comment: Is this always the case that R is always the priority for SR flip flops? Would it be invalid to say that Q(t+1) is undefined for when both S and R are asserted?

Comment: @GudeGude, can't say for all SRFFs, only this one. If it's not defined for the one you have, don't presume - hunt down manufacturer's documentation that states it otherwise consider it undefined. That's the best route to reliable design, especially for mass production over years. It's a sound rule for all circuit design. And, yep, saying that it is incorrect, please see my answer.